# Pyspark - Combine data frames and find nearest timestamü

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, timestamp

I have the following two tables:

Table 1:

| machinenumber | timestamp_a | date | Value_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ01 | 2023-03-10 06:53:26 | 2023-03-10 | e_test |
| XYZ02 | 2023-03-10 07:25:26 | 2023-03-10 | m_test |

Table 2:

| machinenumber | timestamp_startrun | date | Value_nubmer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ01 | 2023-03-10 06:58:11 | 2023-03-10 | 10 |
| XYZ02 | 2023-03-10 07:30:10 | 2023-03-10 | 11 |

I want to join both tables so that "timestamp_a" from table 1 is linked to the nearest "timestamp_startrun" from table 2:

Expected output:

| machinenumber | timestamp_a | timestamp_startrun | date | Value_type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ01 | 2023-03-10 06:53:26 | 2023-03-10 06:58:11 | 2023-03-10 | e_test | 10 |
| XYZ02 | 2023-03-10 07:25:26 | 2023-03-10 07:30:10 | 2023-03-10 | m_test | 11 |

I know that I probably have to use a window function but I'm not that familar with them yet.Does anybody have a idea how to do this in Pyspark?